# How to get sticky notes attached to pdf documents in my web application?

Tags: web-apps, pdf, web-development, pdf-viewer

To have preview for PDF documents in my web application

> I am converting the PDF documents into HTML using **pdf2HtmlEx tool**

***And this works fine for***

- Highlight
- Underline
- Strikethrough
- Rectangular box

***And not for***

> Sticky notes added PDFs - the converted html contains only note icon -
>   missing text/comment within sticky note.

Someone kindly help me to get sticky notes attached in my pdf document while viewing in my web application.